# Does mirage go invisible if reviving himself?

Tags: apex-legends

I was once playing with a mirage teammate and we were in a fight with another squad and i got downed, and when mirage killed them he came and i noticed that when he was reviving me he got invisible, but i never saw what would happen if a mirage had a golden knockdown shield and revived himself, does he go invisible like if reviving someone else or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Mirage does indeed go invisible when reviving but doesn't go invisible when reviving himself.

This is probably to keep the perk from being powerful and adds to mirages abilities and role in a squad.

Here is a Reddit discussion on why this should be a feature.

https://www.reddit.com/r/apexlegends/comments/gmdt2g/opinion_mirage_should_go_invisible_when/

A video of Mirage going invisible normally

As a mirage player, I understand the frustration that can come from realizing this, I also thought he turned invisible when I originally picked him up as well.

I hope this helps!